# Android JSON Exception (End of input at character 0 of)

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm trying retrive server json data.

My code:
MainActivity

```
String url = "http://........com/...../...."
String[] params = new String[]{url};
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
try {
String response = jsonParser.execute(url).get();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jsonObje = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
}
```

JSONParser.JAVA

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
String responseText="";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            //GIVE ERROR THIS LINE!
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            //ERROR LINE!

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
```

Error: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Json file:

```
{"PersonelID":2,"PersonelAdıSoyadı":"New Driver","PersonelTelefon":"","PersonelMail":"driver@mail.com","PersonelPassword":null,"PersonelTipi":1,"AracID":0,"SirketID":20,"SuccessCode":1}
```

Comment: if the value of your variable  "response"  contains this string "{"PersonelID":2,"PersonelAdıSoyadı":"New Driver",..."  you get the error because that is not a JSON Array! Do not use `JSONArray` use `JSONObject` instead

Comment: Can show us the full exception?

Answer (score 0):

just call this method by passing input stream

```
    private String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    Log.d(TAG, "readInputStream()");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    try {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();

            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }

    }

    return "RESULT_EMPTY";

}
```

,then `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);`

Answer (score 0):

the reason for the error is because you are expecting a JSONArray which in this form

```
["item1","item2,"item3"]
```

while `JSONObject` is in this form `{"key": "value"}`
so in your example, you are getting `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`. so change your code to

```
String response = jsonParser.execute(url).get();

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resonse);
String PersonelMail= jsonObject.getString("PersonelMail");
 //...... the same for  the other values
```

see this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) for more about JSON parsing . also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179838/how-to-map-a-json-to-a-java-model-class/48180302#48180302) on how to use Gson a library created by Google to map JSON easily.

Answer (score 0):

My codes is true. Problem is very different places.

I'm adding internet permission to Android manifest, problem solved.

Thank you all.