# How to fetch json data from an array using volley Library?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-studio, android-volley

**My json Data**

```
{"code":1200,"message":"Data Retrieved","data":[{"id":1,"name":"Vangipurapu Venkata Sai Laxman","skills":"Cricketer, Batsman","image":"https:\/\/qph.ec.quoracdn.net\/main-qimg-4f5029c4319b41270f5643d461979645-c"},{"id":2,"name":"Himesh Reshammiya","skills":"music director, singer, producer, lyricist, distributor and actor","image":"https:\/\/starsunfolded-1ygkv60km.netdna-ssl.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/01\/Himesh-Reshammiya-nasal-singing.jpg"},{"id":3,"name":"Rajkummar Rao","skills":"Indian actor","image":"https:\/\/encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com\/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhShfz5g33MOXBKtLlEXo16uuxEpHFL8NYQE2lg071avavYeKr"},{"id":4,"name":"Pusarla Venkata Sindhu","skills":"badminton player","image":"https:\/\/encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com\/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTC0wYTxk72MNx5IADgDDMAqUz9AEyfR6UZexWNqn_fKFNZCLz-"}]}
```

This is my Mainactivity

**MainActivity.java**

```
JsonArrayRequest rqst = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
         new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {   
                  for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                      try {    
                          JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                          DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                          dataSet.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                          dataSet.setImage(obj.getString("image"));                                 
                          dataSet.setSkills(obj.getString("skills"));
                          list.add(dataSet);
                      } catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }    
                  }
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
```

What changes Should i Made to fetch the data? I should fetch that data in to an listview.

Comment: Here is example how to do it https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: see this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179838/how-to-map-a-json-to-a-java-model-class

Answer (score 0):

you are expecting a JSONArray but  your response is a JSON object that contains a JSON array.

modofy your request to a `StringRequest`

```
    StringRequest strtRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                   JSONArray arr=obj.getJSONArray("data");
                   for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
                          JSONObject jo=arr.getJSONObject(i);
                          DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                          dataSet.setName(jo.getString("name"));
                          dataSet.setImage(jo.getString("image"));                                 
                          dataSet.setSkills(jo.getString("skills"));
                          list.add(dataSet);
            }
 }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                             // error
                 Log.d("Error.Response", response);
           }
        }
    ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... It worked

Comment: glad it helped, read more about JSON and google Gson. Gson will save you a lot of time